# Concatenate multiple HTML text inputs with stored variable

Tags: html, forms, string-concatenation

I am trying to create a simple html form which asks for some details from a user and once this has been submitted will add the text to some predetermined text in a text box.

Example of this...

Text box 1 - Enter Name
Text box 2 - Enter Age
Text box 3 - Enter Location

When this is submitted I would like this to be added preferably into a text box or even just output has text on an html page with other text already stored so the output would maybe be something like "Hello John, you are 25 years old and from London".

What I have is very basic:

```
    <html>
    <form>
    Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
    Age: <input type="text" name="age"><br>
    Location: <input type="text" name="location"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
    <html>
```

Beyond this I'm unsure how to get all the values into another text box with the other predetermined text.

Any help or direction in this would be appreciated.

Comment: @Mr.Alien I updated my question with what I had managed so far before becoming stuck on the next step to take.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a solution, so get the elements using `document.getElementById()`, attach an event handler to the `click` event using `element.onclick = function () {}` and `alert()` to show a message box.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/YEb6W/)

**JavaScript**

```
var button = document.getElementById('test');
var name = document.getElementById('name');
var age = document.getElementById('age');
var location = document.getElementById('location');

button.onclick = function () {
    var str = 'Hello ' + name.value + 
        ', you are ' + age.value +
        ' years old and from ' + location.value;
    alert(str);
};
```

**HTML**

```
<label>
    Enter name: 
    <input id="name" />
</label>
<br />
<label>
    Enter age: 
    <input id="age" />
</label>
<br />
<label>
    Enter location: 
    <input id="location" />
</label>
<br />
<button id="test">Test</button>
```

### Edit

To output it to the page use `element.innerHTML` to set the contents of an element.

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Tyriar/5ERRG/)

```
output.innerHTML = str;
```

Comment: This is really useful.  Instead of using alert for a message box can this be output on the page so the text can be copied?

Comment: Updated with outputting to page.

Answer (score 0):

```js
function yes() {
var button = document.getElementById('test');
var name = document.getElementById('name');
var age = document.getElementById('age');
var location = document.getElementById('location');
    var str = 'Hello ' + name.value + 
        ', you are ' + age.value +
        ' years old and from ' + location.value;
    document.getElementById('test').innerHTML=str;
};
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<label>
    Enter name: 
    <input id="name" />
</label>
<br />
<label>
    Enter age: 
    <input id="age" />
</label>
<br />
<label>
    Enter location: 
    <input id="location" />
</label>
<br />
<button onclick="yes()">Test</button>
<p id="test"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Add some explanation to avoid this post to consider as low quality post by `stackoverflow`.